# Working hours time keeping application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I`m trying to create a time keeping application for employees. I just wanted to know what the best approach would be. Create a table with all the dates, once a month and process them, or just store the different ones.

The normal schedule should be Monday to Friday 8 hours per day, but there could be instances of less than 8 hours, or more hours, plus Saturday and Sunday that should be treated differently, furthermore all this data needs to be stored it`s not a one time thing.
My conundrum is that I cannot find the best solution for that particular table. Should I store only the special events like less than 8 or more and so on... Furthermore the app should take into consideration national holidays...

asp.net application c# if it helps, sql and all that jazz.

Comment: You could have a separate column for the start and end time in your Employee table. You could store this as a datetime data type and ignore the date element (use DateTime.Min within your application as the date element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're more likely to be interested/using the current data, and only interested in older stuff for auditing/occasional usage, I'd go with one table for the "current" dataset for all employees, and a table for "historic" datasets.

Each table would have a reference to the employee, along with the start datetime and end datetime, and perhaps the "task" they're logging the time against (such as holiday, sickness, public holiday, project a, project b, etc).

When you reach the month end, and the data becomes "locked", you can process it from the current table, into the historic table and do whatever you want.

That way, you can keep your current table down to the minimum data you require, but also keep a history of the older data.

You could look at using SQL CDC and it's retention policies for doing this and clearing out data you don't want.

Or you could simply do it yourself in SQL via jobs / c# via code.

Certainly, that's the way the enterprise-level time management project we use at my company appears to work :)

problem with storing calendars etc is that you're effectively building a lot of data that may not work for all employees, all of the time.
You'll need to create separate calendars for those edge cases. You'll also have to populate it up a good few years in advance / ensure you populate it for the next year before it's required.
Similarly, what happens if the company decides it's going to close for a day or two on short notice? Lets say you find asbestos in the bathrooms, so they have to close the office (or perhaps HALF the office) for a day. You'd need to update your calendar table to reflect that, else you'll have exceptions for everyone on that day.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating such an application couple of years ago.
I had a table in database that was used as a calendar. It had fields like:

- date
- day_name (Monday, Tuesday, etc)
- is_holiday (is this day a holiday - do people work on that day or not - sundays also had this flag set to true)
- is_sathurday
- is_sunday

And couple more, but I don't remember. It was very good solution. Not only you know when the holiday was or whether employee worked on Sunday, but you can also build calendars for employees.

Table was inserted during installation (by stored proc), using - as far as I remember - Gauss algorithm.

Top date was 2030 or 2040.

Comment: and did you generate all the dates ? from "now" to 2030 ? or did you assign a sql job to add them each 15th of the month, for example

Comment: or did you just store each one of them

Comment: I generated all the dates during installation. Dates were genereted by sql stored procedure. All dates from 1950 to 2030 or 2040. But you probably don't need such period. You can generate them from NOW to 2030 or whatever you want :)